# Error while putting activity inside the favourite page

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-vectordrawable

I have a vector drawable image. It's use is that whenever it is clicked the activity will be added to the favouritepage.

here is my kinematics.java class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kinematics);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.phy_lawtoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(R.string.Kinematics);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.phy_draw);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_phy);
    phy_law_toggel = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.Close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(phy_law_toggel);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.phy_lawtoolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    phy_law_toggel.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.phy_law_web);
    fav = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fav);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mathscribe/Kinematics.html");

    final ArrayList<String> mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Favouritepage favr = new Favouritepage();
    kine = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    final ArrayList<String> resultArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("mfavlist");

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            webView.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });

    fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            resultArray.add(kine);
            }
    });


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (phy_law_toggel.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

favouritepage.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favouritepage);

    ArrayList<String> mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Favouritepage.this,Favouritepage.class);
    intent.putExtra(" mfavlist ", mfavlist);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Whenever I click on the vectordrawable icon the app crashes and shows the `NullPointerException` error

Here is my crashlog

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.alpit.formula2, PID: 2991
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.alpit.formula2.Kinematics$2.onClick(Kinematics.java:71)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4802)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20102)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things:

- First of all remove extra white space around the name in favoritepage.java
- Also use `putStringArrayListExtra` instead of `putExtra`

  ```
  intent.putStringArrayListExtra("mfavlist", mfavlist);
  ```

**EDIT 1**

You might also consider to actually specify the *other* activity when you create your `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Favouritepage.this, Kinematics.class);
```

Comment: thanks for your help.it really helps.the activity is added to the favourite list but then also my app crashes and the same error keeps coming

Comment: @arunodaysingh On which line does it crash?

Comment: @arunodaysingh What is the purpose of this line in your Kinematics.java: `final ArrayList<String> mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>();`?

Comment: @arunodaysingh Also where do you specify in your Intent that you are calling Kinematics.java activity?

Comment: the line final ArrayList<String> mfavlist = new ArrayList<String>() doesnot have anything related to the code.i was working on this from past few days and forgot to erase it.

Comment: the app is crashing on this line resultArray.add(kine);

Comment: i had put the intent line which you mentioned in the edited part but then also the same error keeps coming.can you tell me why??

Comment: @arunodaysingh The error is very specific and it means that your `resultArray` is, indeed, `null`. The only way that could happen is if you don't put the `Extra` the right way or don't read `Extra` the right way. Double check your code. That's where the error is. Can you confirm in favoritepage.java that your array is not null? Then confirm that you use the same string name in both favoritepage and kinetics activity.